# ServiceStack: Serve static files with extension docx and zip

Tags: servicestack, mime-types, static-files

I have in the root of my web application two files: file1.docx and file2.zip neither of these files are served and instead I receive a 403 error. If I change the extension to .txt then the file gets served with no problem which leaves me to believe that SS looks at the extension?

.docx and .zip are in IISs list of known MIME types so I'm not sure why SS would serve the one and not the other as I thought the only check was that a physical file existed at that location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, you need to add it to the `Config.AllowFileExtensions` safe whitelist, e.g:

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig { 
    AllowFileExtensions = { "docx", "zip" }
});
```